# SSIS Foreach Loop Folder as variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I need to set the Folder in my Foreach loop to a variable location.  I tried just adding the location to my package configuration, and it acted like it worked, but when I opened the configuration file, it wasn't there.

I had it set to Foreach File Enumerator, with the path hardcoded, and Retrieve fully qualified file name.  My variable Mappings have a variable CurrentFile with index 0.

So, I've changed it to a Foreach From Variable Enumerator, with a SourceFiles variable of \server\path*.*.  But now it's complaining about that CurrentFile, that the type of value being assigned differs from the variable type (string).

I'm guessing that I need to somehow use the Expressions with the Enumerator on the Collections tab?  How?

- General: Foreach Loop Container
- Collection: Foreach From Varialbe Enumerator; Variable is User::SourcePath; Expressions (not used)
- Variable Mappings: Variable User::CurrentFile, Index 0
- Expressions: (not used)

Error: 0xC001F009 at MyPackage: The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::CurrentFile" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.
Error: 0xC001C012 at Foreach Loop Container: ForEach Variable Mapping number 1 to variable "User::CurrentFile" cannot be applied.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A co-worker showed me how to get it to work.  Do NOT change it to "Foreach from Variable Enumerator", but leave it as "Foreach File Enumerator".

- Collection: Foreach File Enumerator; put in a folder and files in the Enumerator configuration.  Under Expressions, set the Directory to a user variable pointing to the directory (it will take precedence to the folder you've entered); set the FileSpec to a user variable pointing to the files (which will take precendence to the Files you've entered).

> ```
> Directory @[User::SourcePath]  (value: \\server\directory)
> FileSpec @[User::CopyFileName] (value: *.*)
> ```

- Variable Mappings: Variable User::Current File, index 0
- Expressions: (not used)

Comment: Just a minor clarification to this great solution.  There are several places to change the Expressions values on a ForEach Loop.  Make sure to use the one on the Collection tab, directly below the Enumerator field, as it is the only place this "Directory" value exists.

Comment: Over 10 years later, at a different job, and this helped me!