# SSIS Foreach Loop - Excel Sheets - 'xlnm#_FilterDatabase' (phantom / ghost sheet)

Tags: sql-server, excel, for-loop, ssis

Following the instructions on a MSSQLTips blog post, I have setup package with a Foreach Loop to loop through all sheets in a workbook and import the data into a table.

The loop is finding the correct sheet (**`'11-18$'`**), and then the same sheet with a longer name (**`'11-18$'_xlnm#_FilterDatabase`**).  The extra sheet is causing `data duplication` and error messages such as `"Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[SourceSheet]" specifies failure on truncation`.

- How to make the loop exclude the 'xlnm#_FilterDatabase' object?
- Why is the loop duplicating the sheet data?

MSSQLTips blog post-- [Read Data From Multiple Excel Worksheets SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4157/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-worksheets-with-sql-server-integration-services/)

### **Foreach Loop setup:**

> **Variable**
>
> - **Variable** is `Name:'Sheet Name'`, 
>     `Scope:'Import_AXExtractAgristatsInventory'`
>     (package name), `Date type:'String'`, `Value:'11-18$'`
>
> **Foreach Loop Editor**
>
> - **Collection Enumerator** is `Foreach ADO.NET Schema Rowset Enumerator`
> - **Connection Provider** is `.Net Providers for OleDb\Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider`
> - **Connection File** is a path to `\\filepath\file.XLSX`
> - **Connection Advanced Extended Property** is `Excel 12.0`
> - **Connection Variable Mapping** is `Variable:='User:SheetName'`, 
>     `Index:='2'`
> - **Connection string** is `Data Source=C:\filepath\file.xlsx;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;`

---

**Update: `Foreach ADO.NET Schema Rowset Enumerator` and `Set Restrictions` limitation**

I thought the `Set Restrictions` option would do the trick (to exclude the phantom sheets) with an expression such as `!=*_FilterDatabase*`, but according to an ebook excerpt online at flylib, wildcards are not an option ...

> The ADO.NET Schema Rowset Enumerator provides a way to enumerate the
>   schema for a data source. For example, you can enumerate the tables in
>   a database, catalogs on a server, or columns for a table. For each
>   schema, you can filter the results in a number of ways. Figure 13.13
>   shows the Foreach ADO.NET Schema Rowset Enumerator Editor with the
>   Catalogs schema selected.
>
> There is no way to specify a wildcard for restrictions.
>
> *Reference: [Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Integration Services: Stock Foreach Enumerators](https://flylib.com/books/en/1.154.1.93/1/)*
>
> - *Figure 13.13. The Foreach ADO.NET Schema Rowset Enumerator provides a way to enumerate database schema.*
> - *Figure 13.14 shows the Tables Schema Restrictions dialog box for the 
>     Tables schema.*

---

**Update: Debugging values in loop**

In an effort to debug the sheet objects in the loop, I finally found a way to stop the loop and display the sheet name. I found an article on Pragmatic Works Blog Post which shows how to use `Script Task`, `Break Point`, and `Watch Window` to display that active loop value-- [Looping through resultset with foreach loop](http://blog.pragmaticworks.com/looping-through-a-result-set-with-the-foreach-loop).

[image]

---

These are suggested SO questions...

- (1) [SSIS Foreach Loop Folder as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466554/ssis-foreach-loop-folder-as-variable), (2) [SSIS with Excel sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086976/ssis-with-excel-sheets), (3) [SSIS Looping through Excel Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572766/ssis-looping-through-excel-sheets), (4) [Foreach Loop Container gives an error after 5 iterations. SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447932/foreach-loop-container-gives-an-error-after-5-iterations-ssis)

Comment: I found an SSIS solution to this problem on a [Blog by Todd Chitt](https://toddchitt.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/multitab/), but his solution means I would have to re-work my package from `Foreach Loop > DataFlow` to a more complicated process `DataFlow > [Script Task] and [RecordSet destination] > Foreach Loop`.  Not sure if that is the change I am looking for.

Comment: Same exact question was asked on [SQLServerCenter Forums](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1780577/SSIS--ForEach-Loop-Container-Excel-load), but i don't see an answer was given.

Comment: Some other options to consider: [Option A -- extra dummy task in your foreach loop with an expression on the precedence constraint to the next task](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/07/foreach-excel-worksheet-enumerator.html?_sm_au_=iVVq2MjqVNWPTfHF), and [Option B -- Custom SSIS Component: Foreach Excel Worksheet Enumerator](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/07/custom-ssis-component-foreach-excel.html?_sm_au_=iVVq2MjqVNWPTfHF)

Comment: I've done some more testing and found the weirdest thing... When I open the source excel file on my desktop and then run the package, the "FilterDatatbase" phantom sheets are no longer found in the loop. (・_・ヾ ?  This is just an interesting note.  Still researching the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the requirement, and I am shocked that it turns out to be fairly simple.  I am happy to share it with you here.

All configurations are still in use from the [MSSQLTips blog post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4157/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-worksheets-with-sql-server-integration-services/) that I reference in my original question using the the `Foreach ADO.NET Schema Rowset Enumerator` configurations.  I added one small bit of logic...

**STEPS: Logic to Skip Sheet Names**

> 1. **Variable (boolean) - FINDSTRING**
>
>    - Setup a variable called `varIsInvalidSheet_DisableTask` and set expression to `FINDSTRING(@[User::varSheetName] ,"FilterDatabase",1 ) > 0`
>    - [FINDSTRING (SSIS Expression): Microsoft Docs/ SSIS/ Expressions/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)
> 2. **Data Flow Task (Properties> Expression> Disable)**
>
>    - We want to stop the Data Flow Task when it is an invalid sheet.  To do so...
>    - Left Click the Data Flow task, go to the Properties pane, in the Expressions section choose the elipse icon ('...') and choose
>        '`Disable`' property and for the expression simply add the variable
>        created in prior step '`@[User::varIsInvalidSheet_DisableTask]`'
> 3. **Run debugger to verify the settings take effect**
>
>    - All sheets are found but the phantom sheets have a Disable TRUE property, and the task is ignored.

Here are some screenshots of these steps

[image: ssis_task-expression-disable]

[image: ssis_debug-loop-sheet-objects]